# how to display a list on content items from the front end?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard 1.6. I have created a content type 'Questions', attached it to a form, so the 'Questions' can be viewed from the front end, and the answers submitted back, by the logged in user - storing as a content item (which is viewed from the dashboard).

Users won't have access to the dashboard so how can I display a list of content items from the front end, and then how I can refine that search to display only content items that have been submitted by that user, for that content type?

Anyone any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways: making a custom controller or using the projection module with custom queries. (http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-5)